# Creating a matrix in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like this:

```
   score user product
0   2    2a       A
1   3    2a       B
2   1    2a       C
3   5    2b       A
4   0    2b       C
5   2    2c       B
```

I want a matrix structure somewhat like this:

```
        A  B  C
2a      2  3  
2b      5     0
2c         2
```

Where the blank spaces mean missing values. How do I get this structure?

Comment: I think it is a bad question because you did not describe your own efforts. You simply have an input and desired output, expecting others to fill in the code in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='user',columns='product', values='score'))
product    A    B    C
user                  
2a       2.0  3.0  1.0
2b       5.0  NaN  0.0
2c       NaN  2.0  NaN

print (df.set_index(['user','product']).score.unstack())
product    A    B    C
user                  
2a       2.0  3.0  1.0
2b       5.0  NaN  0.0
2c       NaN  2.0  NaN
```

If need replace `NaN` by some values like `0` add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or parameter `fill_value`:

```
print (df.pivot(index='user',columns='product', values='score').fillna(0).astype(int))
product  A  B  C
user            
2a       2  3  1
2b       5  0  0
2c       0  2  0

print (df.set_index(['user','product']).score.unstack(fill_value=0))
product  A  B  C
user            
2a       2  3  1
2b       5  0  0
2c       0  2  0
```

EDIT:

If error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

It means there are duplicates and some aggregation is necessary.

One slower solution is [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), default aggregate function is `np.mean`, but can be change to another function like `sum`:

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='user',columns='product', values='score', aggfunc=np.mean))
product    A    B    C
user                  
2a       2.0  3.0  1.0
2b       5.0  NaN  0.0
2c       NaN  2.0  NaN
```

Faster solution with `groupby`, aggreagte by function like `mean`, `sum`... and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['user','product']).score.mean().unstack())
product    A    B    C
user                  
2a       2.0  3.0  1.0
2b       5.0  NaN  0.0
2c       NaN  2.0  NaN
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.
Getting this error.